# how to remove empty spaces from my output while using findall()?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say this is my data frame:

```
country     Edition   Event          Athletes               Medal      Gender   Score
Germany     1990    discus throw      HAJOS, Alfred          gold       M        3
Germany     1990    discus throw      HIRSCHMANN, Otto       silver     M        2
Germany     1990    100m freestyle    DRIVAS, Dimitrios      gold       W        3
Germany     1990    1200m freestyle   DRIVAS, Dimitrios      silver     W        2
US          2008    1200m freestyle   MALOKINIS, Ioannis     gold       M        1
US          2008    1200m freestyle   HAJOS, Alfred          silver     M        2
US          2009    400m freestyle    CHASAPIS, Spiridon     gold       W        3
France      2010    400m freestyle    CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold       W        3
France      2010    400m freestyle    CHOROPHAS, Efstathios  gold       M        3
France      2010    discus throw      HAJOS, Alfred          Bronze     M        1
France      2011    discus throw      ANDREOU, Joannis       silver     W        2
Spain       2011    300m freestyle    BURKE, Thomas          gold       M        3
```

I am trying to find How many different events have numbers in their description are in the dataset?

what i did is :

`df['Event'].str.findall('\d+')` but it is also giving empty spaces in the output bcoz of which if we take the count it will be wrong. Can anyone tell me what i have to do ? to remove empty spaces from my output?

Comment: Why don't you use `.nunique()` on the column? Also keep in mind that your end goal seems to be absolutely different from the title of this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get the unique items from the column Edition, you should be  using `df.Event.unique()`. This gets all the unique values from the column and stores them in a list.

If you need only the count, you can use `df.Event.nunique()`.

```
# Get the unique items in a list.
ls = df.Event.unique()
# Initiate a counter.
ls_count = 0

# Loop over list and increment counter each time
# a element starts with an integer.
for i in ls:
    if i[0].isdigit() == True:
        ls_count += 1
```

Comment: i need the count of those events who have numbers in there description! for example: 100m freestyle

Comment: get the unique values in a list; initiate a counter; loop over the elements of the count and increase the counter each time an integer is present in the element of the list. I have updated the answer, check if that works for your use-case.

Comment: @prabs if you find any answer useful, please mark them as the right answer. this helps the person who helped to increase their reputation.

Comment: Why use `.` column access over `[ ]`?

Comment: No particular reason. In this case, there is no much difference between using df.Event or df['Event']

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.Event[df.Event.str.match(r'^\d+')].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you use contains you can do this to get true/false value counts:

```
df['Event'].str.contains('\d+')                                                                                                                                                      

0     False
1     False
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
11     True
Name: Event, dtype: bool

df['Event'].str.contains('\d+').value_counts()                                                                                                                                       

True     8
False    4
Name: Event, dtype: int64
```

To account for duplicated, the code can be changed to:

```
df3['Event'].drop_duplicates().str.contains('\d+').value_counts()                                                                                                                    

True     4
False    1
Name: Event, dtype: int64
```

Here we can see the True count is 1 for 1200m freestyle:

```
df3['Event'][3:6]                                                                                                                                                                    

3    1200m freestyle
4    1200m freestyle
5    1200m freestyle
Name: Event, dtype: object

df3['Event'][3:6].drop_duplicates().str.contains('\d+').value_counts()                                                                                                               

Out[380]: 
True    1
```

Comment: if i only want 8 as an output then what should i do?

Comment: You can do df['Event'].str.contains('\d+').value_counts()[1]

Comment: will it give me unique records? because there can be more than one event having same name!

Comment: well you can drop duplicates if it does. Just curious, is that the answer you expected? If you think there is a case where it won't work, can you add that line to your dataset?

Comment: like for example there are 3 1200m freestyle records and your solution will give 3 true and you will count it as 3 records but it should be counted as one record.

Comment: @prabs I think i updated to show it working as giving 1 count for the  3 1200m freestyle records , so the full solution above it should work just right.